# Correct way to ask a question

Tags: terminology

Ok so, I made a statement she didn't hear me so her response was, "What you said". I told her she was wrong.  Please help us solve this debate. If a person ask the question, " What you said"? Is that correct? I say No, I need some clarity.

Comment: "What you said" would be a valid informal *response* to certain types of questions, basically confirming that what the interrogator stated is true.  Quite idiomatic and context-sensitive, though.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not correct English. The short answer is that a sentence that begins with a question word like *what* and ends with a question mark (or rising intonation at the end of the sentence as this is the only way to indicate that you're actually asking a question when physically speaking with someone) has got to be a question. And all properly-formed questions in English follow this pattern: *[question word] [helping verb] [subject] [main verb]?*. All English grammar books are pretty clear on this rule. Therefore, the correct response should be:

> What did you say?

Answer (score 0):

In spoken English there are very many ways of saying that you did not hear what someone has just said. Care is needed because some of them are considered impolite by some people. In addition to "what did you say?" they include:

- What? In BrE many people would regard that as impolite but is said to be used without impoliteness in upper class circles
- Eh? Also considered as impolite but not by the same people.
- Pardon? Not impolite at all for some people, but others (my parents, for example) regard it as rude. See, [Mumsnet](https://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/am_i_being_unreasonable/1267310-To-think-saying-What-is-rude)
- I beg your pardon? Probably the safest to use.